# How to create a Let’s Encrypt self signed certificate for a subdomain only? (error in post)

Tags: linux, subdomain, lets-encrypt, self-signed

How to create a Let’s Encrypt self signed certificate for a subdomain?

To be specific:

- `sub.domain.com` (needs a certificate and points to an ip address)
- `domain.com` (does not point to anything)

When following [the following instructions](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/ssl/install-lets-encrypt-to-create-ssl-certificates), I get the following errors:

```
>>> sudo -H ./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone -d sub.domain.com --register-unsafely-without-email
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator standalone, Installer None
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
tls-sni-01 challenge for sub.domain.com
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. sub.domain.com (tls-sni-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: Timeout

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: sub.domain.com
   Type:   connection
   Detail: Timeout

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
   your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
   firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
   client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
   that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.
```

Comment: Are you running the commands on the server you want to setup?

Comment: @jrtapsell No, that was my problem - if you post an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the commands on the server, cause the command verifies you control the domain, so if it's not on the server it can't verify correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Let's Encrypt Certificate for subdomain without pointing domian to any root.

- Login to DNS management and create A NAME Record for subdomian. For A NAME you would need IP address

  - Verify sub.domian.com is accessible over internet.
  - run script for sub.domian.com.

https://zerossl.com/free-ssl/#crt can be also used to generate certificates and key however it would need some manual step to create .well-known and aceme-challenge folder need to be created in sub.domian.com /DocumentRoot